# Parse field names and types from TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a generic utility functions to help me work with TFRecord objects. For this, I am looking to parse field names and types from a TFRecord object (in Python).

The [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#reading_a_tfrecord_file_2) gives some example on how to print these.

```
filenames = [FILENAME]
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(1):
  example = tf.train.Example()
  example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
  print(example)
```

This prints output such as:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "class"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 75
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "id"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "aaf19c8d0"
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "\377\330.....
```

I can even print the individual field info (knowing the name) as

```
example.features.feature["class"]
```

Which prints out

```
int64_list {
  value: 75
}
```

So most of the information seems to be there. This data has two fields "class" (type tf.int64) and "image" (type tf.string).

The `Example` object seems to be of type `tensorflow.core.example.example_pb2.Example`. Which has some functions such as keys(), items(), ... but none of these give me access to the feature names and types as far as I can see.

There also seems to be some kind of generic "id" field in the output that is not part of the original list of fields. And the type tf.int64 seems to appear as a list with one item. So it is close but not quite. And I have trouble accessing the field names and types through the Python objects. I'd rather not start parsing the string output, and guessing type mappings from it.

So I guess the question is, is it possible for me to parse the actual TFRecord format from the file itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try get keys like this:

```py
    list(example.features.feature.keys())
```

And you will have a list with all the feature names inside